# tsc vs babel: a better transpilation/compiler workflow

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I’m working on an ESNext TypeScript project. Currently I’m having some difficulty running my bundler (Rollup) and unit tests (Mocha/Chai). I’ve been quite confused by using `tsc` or `babel` for my compilation process, and I just can’t seem to wrap my head around how all of it’s going to work.

So far, I have the following configs:

tsconfig.json (main config for the project; used in rollup.config.json)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "three"
    ], 
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

rollup.config.js (rollup file for main project module bundling)

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import builtins from '@joseph184/rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default [
    {
        input: './src/index.ts',
        plugins: [
            typescript(),
        ],
        external: [
            "three"
        ],
        output: [
            {
                file: pkg.module,
                format: 'es'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        input: './src/index.ts',
        plugins: [
            resolve({
                preferBuiltins: true,
                mainFields: ['module', 'main'],
            }),
            globals({
                process: true,
                global: true,
                dirname: true,
                filename: true
            }),
            builtins(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript(),
            babel({
                babelrc: true
            }),
        ],
        external: [
            "three"
        ],
        output: [ // Required; Array = multiple outputs
            {
                file: pkg.main,
                format: 'umd',
                name: 'Divine'
            },
            {
                file: "lib/divine.cjs.js",
                format: 'cjs'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

.babelrc (babel options for the main project’s module bundling)

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "entry",
            "debug": "true"
        }],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ],
    "compact": "auto",
    "exclude": [
        "./src/**/test/**/*.spec.ts",
        "./node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.test.json (`tsc` config used for `mocha` with `ts-node` as the compiler)

```
{
    "compililerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "types": [
            "chai",
            "mocha",
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "src/core/loggingsystem/test",
            "src/core/messagesystem/test"
        ]
    }
}
```

My main question is: which should I use for esnext to es5 (for most browser support)? I want to work in ESNext code, but I want to have my build steps with the least friction possible. Is it better to use `tsc` natively, or should I have Babel mixed in/fully used? I’ve been having a very difficult time with my builds as I’m still quite unsure of how it should all fit together.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The real question is "which browsers do you _really_ want to target"? Because almost all of them support modern JS and don't need ES5 transpilation at all. If you want to still support IE11, then it's probably worth making a special ES5 bundle only for that one platform instead of serving ES5 to everyone.

Comment: I don't have any browsers in specific to target. That said, as things are moving to es5 in general, it would be best to target that version as most will be updated. I'm simply trying to get this working for Electron, of which I'm also going to have the builds require version updates before usage

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what es5 is - es5 is the _old_ version of JS, ecmascript 262 revision 5. It's the one you used to have to convert things to because lots of newer JS features weren't supported yet. Years ago. The current version of JS has too many names used by different people, and so is usually marked as "esnext" even though it's really  "es-right-now". The current version of JS is ecmascript 262 revision 9. If your target is electron, there is literally no reason to ever compile to legacy es5. It supports modern JS just fine.

Comment: Thank you Mike, this helps me narrow my focus and gives me some more to jump on. I appreciate the assistance! I'll update with some more information and post my findings here later on.